# Undefined variable - base_url in include() in Drupal 7 html.tpl.php

Tags: 7

I am getting this error, but everything else is fine; even that variable is getting printed. Then why does the error appear?

> Notice: Undefined variable: base_url in include() (line 26 of htdocs\atins\drupal\sites\all\themes\live\html.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: base_path in include() (line 26 of htdocs\atins\drupal\sites\all\themes\live\html.tpl.php).

This is my code:

```
<a href="<?php print $base_url;?>"><img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/img/logo.png" height="35" width="211" alt="AtinsLive Logo" title="Home" /></a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to bring the variable $base_url and $base_path into the global scope. At the top of your function or template file add:

```
global $base_path, $base_url;
```

or call `base_path()`

Comment: Actually, `l()` should be used in this case.

Comment: I agree with Kiamlaluno. l() should be used in the case above. Shoaib Nawaz is also correct, the base_path() function is better used. But in the case of being able to use the 2 variables, you can bring them into the global scope. This is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when using $base_url in page.tpl.php in the following:

```
print l(theme('image', array('path'=>path_to_theme().'/css/images/logo_orig.png')), $base_url, array('html' => 'true'));
```

I fixed this by preprocessing `$base_url` in template.php:

```
function yourTheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  global $base_url;
  $vars['base_url'] = $base_url;
}
```

So, I'm thinking you can preprocess you html template as well. This will be cleaner that calling a global in your tpl directly.

Comment: There is no need to use `$base_url` when calling `l()`.

Comment: I guess it already knows where the front page is :-) http://drupal.org/node/469916#comment-1617352